# bazel ignores compiler arguments using --copt

Tags: g++, compiler-optimization, bazel

I'm trying to pass compiler arguments when building with bazel. I want to disable all the optimizations for Bazel to build a simple project. I actually managed to do this without bazel using the windows command line with this piece of code:

**without bazel:**

```
// main.c
#include <iostream>

class Car{
public:
    Car(){std::cout << "default constructor called" << std::endl;}
    Car(Car &&rhs){std::cout << "move constructor called" << std::endl;}
    ~Car(){std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;}
};
int main() {
    Car a = Car();
    return 0;
}
```

running this with the compiler arguments from the terminal:

```
$ `g++ main.c -O0 -fno-elide-constructors'
```

produces the desired output:

```
default constructor called
move constructor called
destructor called
destructor called
```

I was trying to use this argument for bazel too and I found this:
[bazel --copt flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--copt). Upon building with this command:

**with bazel:**

```
$ bazel build --copt="-O0" --copt="-fno-elide-constructors" main:main
```

I receive the warning:

```
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O0'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fno-elide-constructors'
```

and when I run it with:

```
$ bazel-bin\main\main
```

I get the output:

```
default constructor called
destructor called
```

which means bazel did not build the project by disabling optimizations. How can I disable all optimizations when building my project with bazel? Am iImaking a syntax error? What might be the problem here?

This is my BUILD file in main folder:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
)
```

My windows and compiler version in case it might help:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415]
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
```

Comment: You can see from the error message, `cl : Command line warning D9002`, that the compiler is `cl`.  That's MSVC.  Also, an error number like `D9002` is also MSVC's style, not GCC.  Benjamin's answer is clearly correct about the problem being which compiler is getting these options.

Answer (score 1):

Bazel is using MSVC for compilation; manually, you are using GCC. Pass `--compiler=mingw-gcc` to Bazel to have it select GCC.